# Android: different divider height in ExpandableListview

Tags: android, height, parent-child, expandablelistview

I have in my app a custom expandable and I want the divider height is different for header (5dp) and child (1dp). How I could do? This is my code:

bus_info.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableBus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/expandable_borde_padre"
    android:childDivider="@drawable/expandable_borde_hijo"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/expandable"
    android:scrollbars="none"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

expandable.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/expandable_abajo" android:state_empty="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/expandable_arriba" android:state_expanded="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/expandable_abajo" />
</selector>
```

expandable_borde_padre.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="@color/negro"/>
     <size android:height="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

expandable_borde_hijo.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/blanco"/>
    <size android:height="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

If I change the  to 5dp in expandable_borde_padre also changes in the child

expandable_hijo.java

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#000000">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

expandable_padre.java

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fondoExpandablePadre"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp" 
android:background="#000000">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set both divider and childdivider to null.
Use custom header and child views with custom dividers.

for example:

For header:

```
< TextView>

< /TextView>

< View android:height:"5dp">
< /View>
```

for child:

```
< TextView>

< /TextView>

< View android:height:"1dp">
< /View>
```

Comment: i have edited my code. I had forgotten to put my custom child and header